# Use Mailgun API, PHP, getting "T_USE error"

Tags: php, forms, mailgun

I'm trying to work with mailgun API to send mails I get from a form in my website.

I followed these steps :

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

and

```
php composer.phar require mailgun/mailgun-php php-http/curl-client guzzlehttp/psr7
```

My PHP :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])):
    if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])):
        //your site secret key
        $secret = 'MY CAPTCHA KEY DONT WORRY';
        //get verify response data
        $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
        $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);

        if($responseData->success):
            //contact form submission code

            if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) || !isset($_POST['last_name']) || !isset($_POST['email']) || !isset($_POST['subject']) || !isset($_POST['message']) || !isset($_POST['prefcom'])) 
            {
              $errMsg = 'Un problème est survenu avec le formulaire que vous avez soumis,<br> veuillez réessayer ou directement me contacter via le mail inscrit en bas de page.';    
            } 
            else 
            {
                $prenom = $_POST['first_name'];
                $nom = $_POST['last_name'];
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                $subject = $_POST['subject'];
                $message = $_POST['message'];
                $prefcom = $_POST['prefcom'];

                function clean_string($string) 
                {
                    $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
                    return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
                }
                $htmlContent = "
                    <h2>Vous avez reçu un nouveau message</h2>
                    <p><b>Prenom: </b>".clean_string($prenom)."<b> Nom: </b>".clean_string($nom)."</p>
                    <p><b>Email: </b>".clean_string($email)."</p>
                    <p><b>Message: </b>".clean_string($message)."</p>
                    <p><b>Souhaite être contacté par: </b>".clean_string($prefcom)."</p>
                ";
                # Include the Autoloader (see "Libraries" for install instructions)
                require '../vendor/autoload.php';
                use Mailgun\Mailgun;

                # Instantiate the client.
                $mgClient = new Mailgun('MY SECRET MAILGUN KEY DONT WORRY');
                $domain = "MY EMAIL DONT WORRY";

                # Make the call to the client.
                $result = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain, array(
                    'from'    => 'contact <mailgun@MY-DOMAIN-NAME-DONT-WORRY>',
                    'to'      => 'MY NAME <MY MAIL ADRESS>',
                    'subject' => .clean_string($subject).,
                    'text'    => .$htmlContent.
                ));
                $succMsg = 'Votre message a bien été envoyé.';
            }
        else:
            //$errMsg = 'La vérification a échouée, veuillez réessayer.';
            $errMsg = 'La vérification a échoué, veuillez réessayer.';
        endif;
    else:
        $errMsg = 'Veuillez compléter le reCAPTCHA.';
    endif;
else:
endif;
?>
```

The problem is that it doesn't work. WAMP tells me that i have an error at `use Mailgun\Mailgun;` (line 40 if you paste this in an editor). Everything is fine but Mailgun's code (l38 to l52).

I'm a beginner with PHP (started 2 days ago), can't find where the is problem.

Comment: Functions that used in `if` clauses __MUST__ be defined before `if`

Comment: @u_mulder Ok I just moved the function and "require..." "use...".
Now I get my Html Css page, but when I press send, White page and nothing happens.

Comment: And what should happen?

Comment: I should receive an email but nothing happens

Comment: Errors in error log? What is it `'text'    => .$htmlContent.`?

Comment: error logs : `2017/02/03 15:09:16 [warn] 14480#14480: 4096 worker_connections exceed open file resource limit: 1024`.
And `'text' => .$htmlContent.` that I changed to `'text' => $htmlContent` (removed the dots) is supposed to be the message that is going to be sent to me. I was not sure how to use variables as `$htmlContent` with mailgun API...